# How to intercept GET call with Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring data rest with @RepositoryRestResource where all the verbs are automatically handled for all the entities in the system.

There is no controller necessary for my project.

But I do want to perform certain action before the GET call is made to an entity. What is the best way to do this without writing a custom controller?

There are event handlers I can write in Spring Data Rest like @HandleAfterDelete but there are not handlers for GET.

Comment: Did you try HandlerInterceptor?

Comment: Thanks I will try that, is there a way for HandlerInterceptor to only do something for a certain GET call?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is currently no solution which would provide this out of the framework itself. However, there is [a pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1505) which was discussed but not yet implemented as there are still open questions with regard to the universality of `findBy*` methods.

In case you do not need a that general solution the yet suggested `HandlerInterceptor` is the way to go…

```java
public class YourInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler) throws Exception {
        // decide on request.getMethod() what to do next
    }
}
```